# Java, alert parent on object change

Tags: java

I have the following setup in Java,

```
public class Main {

    // starts sub class
    SubClass sub = new SubClass();
    sub.start();

    // sub will keep running and call method alert() on a specif change
    // method alert is void but updates a public variable named status on sub
    while(1==1) {

        // I should ideally be able to catch/read sub status result here
        // how can I do it?
    }
}
```

I'm new to Java so this may not be valid and my approach may be wrong. That being the case please point me in the right direction.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I presume `SubClass.start()` starts a new thread so the parent runs in parallel with the child.  Then the main class can do a [`Object.wait()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait%28%29) on the `sub` object, and the `SubClass` thread can do a [`Object.notify()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#notify%28%29) on the `sub` object.

Comment: I think only two people in the world are able to properly use Object.notify() and the rest of us are meant to use Object.notifyAll().

Answer (score 0):

you should start by putting your code into a main method :)

Answer (score 0):

If your SubClass is not already a Runnable,

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Thread myThread = new Thread(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                //Instantiate your SubClass here and do stuff. You can pass yourself as a parameter if you plan to do callbacks.
            }
        });
        myThread.setDaemon(true);
        myThread.start();
    }
}
```

Alternatively if you've implemented the Runnable interface on SubClass then just use the thread mechanics (wait(), notify(), etc etc).